# Unable to load downloaded Map

Tags: android, here-api

I want to use HERE map offline capabilities, for this i downloaded map for my country using "here we go" app.

Now in my android project i am setting this

```
MapEngine.setOnline(false);
```

But my android project app is unable to load map, it is showing blank area. Since map is already downloaded, I am expecting this to show map from downloaded map version. Do i need to add MapLoader even if i already have downloaded map ? OR I need to call some other method?

I am using premium SDK that does have offline support.

App is working fine with Data connection on if i don't add `setOnline(false)`

Answer (score 0):

Maps downloaded with HERE WeGo app wouldn't be available for your app. You need to download maps through your app.

For downloading maps:
- look at the description in documentation https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-hybrid-plus/topics/maps-offline.html
- look at an example app https://tcs.ext.here.com/sdk_examples/MapDownloader.zip

Comment: Does it mean, downloaded map data cannot be shared across two Here map SDK application ?

Comment: By default, Mobile SDK for Android will use shared storage for maps, but it's possible to configure it and specify a place for store maps. HERE WeGo using their own place for store maps data. If you will develop several apps, then by default they will share same maps without a need for downloading for every app. If you want to share maps with some 3rd party app, then it will depend on how they implemented this part.

Comment: Got it.. Thanks. One more thing, I didn't find any method in MapLoader where i can specify path for map file. Is it available ? If not how can we implement shared map file access.

Comment: Maps will be shared by default, no need to do anything specific. You need to specify path only if you want to store maps in your own location. For this look https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-hybrid-plus/topics/map-service.html